# Can I use only auxiliary verb for passive-voice references?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use only auxiliary verb for passive-voice references?

Here are some examples of what I mean:

Can I say:

> Many devices were fixed last month. And as for those that **haven't**,
> we will look into it.

Or should I say:

> Many devices were fixed last month. And as for those that **haven't
> been**, we will look into it.

Or should I go "all the way":

> Many devices were fixed last month. And as for those that **haven't
> been fixed**, we will look into it.

?

Can I say:

> Many problems were solved that way. And if there are still some that
> **haven’t**, I feel we need to do that ASAP.

Or should I say:

> Many problems were solved that way. And if there are still some that
> **haven’t been**, I feel we need to do that ASAP.

Or should I go "all the way":

> Many problems were solved that way. And if there are still some that
> **haven’t been solved**, I feel we need to do that ASAP.

?

Comment: With _were fixed_ you need _haven't been_. If you used _have been fixed_ you could get away with just _haven't_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kate Bunting commented, we need the 'haven't been' in this example.

> Many devices were fixed last month. And as for those that haven't been [fixed], we will look into it.

The omitted 2nd 'fixed' is shown in brackets and implied.

Without the 'been', it will be

> 'Many devices were fixed last month. And as for those that haven't [fixed], we will look into it.'

There is no parallelism in this case.